# How can I get the time remaining until midnight and also the start of the next week?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an application where users can post. Depending on their account status, they can either post once a day (account type A) or once a week (account type B).

For account type A, I would like to know how to get the remaining time until midnight (preferably in seconds). For example, if the current time is 11PM, it would return 3600 (60 minutes) until midnight. This way I can tell the user that they cannot make another post for 60 minutes.

For account type B, I would like to know how to get the remaining time until a new week starts. Let's assume the new week starts on Sunday.

Comment: why do you need this solution in SQL ? Assuming, user is playing around on your app where there is no need of db interaction, but you still make db call to get remaining time.

Comment: I thought checking in SQL would be best since I am already checking database to see if they already made a post today (or in the week for account type B). What would you recommend?

Comment: IMO, just get the last pos date and time when user logs-in and make calculation afterward with current time. This will definitely reduce overhead to database

Comment: I do agree with @Ravi. If your user logged in, you already have the necessary data to decide about posting. With mysql you would need an additional query with a flow control statement to decide based on the user status, see **[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/daf98d/2)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Account type A:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Account type B:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,NOW(),DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL (6 - WEEKDAY(NOW())) DAY));
```

Comment: Just curious what the "- INTERVAL 1 SECOND" is doing? Is it necessary?

Comment: @user3614030 Looking again I'm not sure why I thought it necessary

Answer (score 0):

Test gives midnight of tonight, and subtracts the Post Date of an A type account. Test2 gives midnight of the end of the week and subtracts from the Post Date of a B type account.

```
select
datediff(ss, PostDateA, convert(datetime,dateadd(dd,1,convert(int,getdate())),109)) as test,
datediff(ss, PostDateB, convert(datetime,dateadd(dd,1,convert(int,dateadd(dd,7-(datepart(dw,getdate())),getdate()))),109)) test2
from
table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) function

Type A(Time in seconds until midnight):

```
 SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)  -
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
```

Type B(Time in seconds until next week | week starts Monday):

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP((CURDATE()+7 - INTERVAL WEEKDAY(CURDATE()+7) Day)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP((CURDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

Account type A:

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, your_time_field, DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(your_time_field, INTERVAL 1 DAY), "%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00"))
FROM your_table;
```

Account type B:

```
SELECT 
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, your_time_field, ((CURDATE() + INTERVAL 1 WEEK) - INTERVAL WEEK(CURDATE()) DAY));
FROM your_table;
```